# Group rows by a certain identifier and update a group id column to track which group they belong

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, stored-procedures

There is a table where the group id column needs to be populated with a generated incremental number like the following example:

```
name batch
a    1
b    1
c    1
d    2
e    2
f    2
g    3
h    3
i    3
j    4
k    4
```

Order does not matter as long as the groups have the same number of elements

Looking for some ideas how this can be achieved.

What i was thinking is to build a stored procedure that iterates through the result set.

Also i have this "pseudo code" that i'm working with, but obviously has issues, and also does not do the update part just kind of selects and I was thinking to create a temp table which seems like an overkill

```
SELECT
  name,
  batch = (ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY name)) % ((Select COUNT(*) from [abc].[dbo].[cdg]) / 30))
FROM
  [abc].[dbo].[cdg] x
```

Comment: Use NTILE : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/ntile-transact-sql

Comment: Is it fixed 3 records per batch ?

Comment: @Prdp that is a parameter but if we get it working with 3, should be able to do it with any

Comment: isn't this just the floor or ceiling of the mod(%)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this Integer division method

```
Declare @param int  = 3

SELECT name,
      ( ( Row_number()OVER(ORDER BY name) - 1 ) / @param  ) + 1 as Batch
FROM   tablename
```

If you want to derive the `@param` from table `count` then use `Count(*) Over()`

```
SELECT name,
      ( ( Row_number()OVER(ORDER BY name) - 1 ) / (Count(*) Over()/30)  ) + 1 as Batch
FROM   tablename
```

To update the `batch` column

```
;with update_cte as
(
SELECT name,
       Batch,
       ( ( Row_number()OVER(ORDER BY name) - 1 ) / @param  ) + 1 as gen_seq
FROM   tablename
)
Update update_cte set Batch = gen_seq
```

Comment: Nice, integer math!  First time I've seen a useful use for it in some time :P

Comment: so lets say the batch column is empty is there any way we can merge in the values we generated?

Comment: @otc - We need to change the `Select` to `Update` statement. Will update my answer

Comment: looks awesome, will test it out in a sec, thanks a lot

Comment: @Prdp I have already a table, it looks like the script above is creating a new one. Is there anything i need to tweak so can update the Batch column of my existing table.

Comment: it worked sry had a moment of confusion for a sec, thanks

Answer (score 2):

Are you looking for something like this. You can use NTILE function.

```
drop table if exists dbo.Tile;

create table dbo.Tile (
    Chr char(1)
);

insert into dbo.Tile (Chr)
values ('a'), ('b'), ('c'), ('d'), ('e')
    , ('f'), ('g'), ('h'), ('i'), ('j')
    , ('k');

declare @Tile int

set @Tile = ceiling((select count(t.Chr) from dbo.Tile t) / 3.)

select
    *
    , ntile(@Tile) over (order by t.Chr) as batch
from dbo.Tile t
```

Comment: Better to use `Count(*) Over()`  instead of separate table hit to count the records. +1 I was editing my answer with this